# 'table index is nil' error when using the Avenir font with fontspec + luatex

Tags: errors, luatex, fontspec

According to [the `fontspec` package's user manual](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) (2017/03/31 v2.6a, Section 5.1, p. 12)

> Fonts known to LuaTEX [...] may be loaded by their standard names as you'd speak them out loud, such as *Times New Roman* or *Adobe Garamond*. [...]
>   The simplest example might be something like
>   `\setmainfont{Cambria}[...]`
>   [...] The 'font name' can be found in various ways, such as by looking in the name listed in a application like `Font Book` on Mac OS X.

My operating system is Mac OS X. The following screenshot shows the *Times New Roman* font in in my `Font Book` application.

[image: The Times New Roman font in Font Book]

The following screenshot shows the `Avenir` font name in my `Font Book` application.

[image: The Avenir font in Font Book]

The following LaTeX document sets the main font of the document to `Times New Roman`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Processing this document with the LuaLaTeX format (i.e. with the LuaLaTeX "engine") results in the following pdf, as expected:

[image: Hello, world!]

However, replacing 'Times New Roman' with 'Avenir' and reprocessing the document with the LuaLaTeX format results in no pdf, and the following error message:

> ERROR: table index is nil.
>
> --- TeX said ---
>   
>   \scan_stop:
>   l.3 \setmainfont{Avenir}
>
> --- HELP ---
>   From the .log file...
>
> The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

What's the problem? Why doesn't the *Avenir* example work whereas the *Times New Roman* one does?

---

**Operating System**: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5
**MacTex distribution**: MacTeX-2017
**LuaTeX**: Version 1.0.4

Comment: Try `\setmainfont{Avenir light}`

Comment: The font you showed us is not Avenir, it's Avenir Book. You have to add that "Book" because it identifies the font in the font family and probably corresponds to your font's name on disk. That's what fontspec can look for.

Comment: @TeXnician: Changing 'Avenir' to 'Avenir Book' works. So thanks. But I'd still like to know why simply writing 'Avenir' doesn't work, whereas writing 'Times New Roman' does work. Why did I not need to write 'Times New Roman Regular' in analogy to 'Avenir Book'?

Comment: @TeXnician: And changing the font to either *Courier* or *Courier Regular* results in an error message.

Comment: @EvanAad please look to my answer: there is where to find these informations on font book, ie the *complete name*

Comment: Font names are complicated beast and even more if there are collection of fonts with similar name. Try to find a name that works but don't try to hard to find a "logical" explanation why it works - there is always at least one odd font that doesn't fit the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know why LuaLaTeX is not able to associate Avenir Book to the upright font; with XeLaTeX it seems to go well.

Actually, if one looks closely, when XeLaTeX is used, the `.ttc` font file in the `/System/Library/Fonts` folder is used, not one of the files in `/Library/Fonts`. Perhaps this is the issue when LuaLaTeX comes into play, because `luaotfload` has a different strategy for choosing fonts.

For LuaLaTeX you need to specify the font names (at least in this case):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Avenir}[
  UprightFont=* Book,             % or Light
  ItalicFont=* Book Oblique,      % or Light Oblique
  BoldFont=* Black,               % or Medium
  BoldItalicFont=* Black Oblique, % or Medium Oblique
]

\begin{document}

Hello, world! \fontname\font

{\itshape Hello \fontname\font}

{\bfseries Hello \fontname\font}

{\bfseries\itshape Hello \fontname\font}

\end{document}
```

This would be needed also with XeLaTeX if you want Medium instead of Black.

### Output with LuaLaTeX

[image]

### Output with XeLaTeX

[image]

### Output with XeLaTeX and just `\setmainfont{Avenir}`

[image]

Comment: How does XeTeX know automatically which fonts within the `Avenir` family to associate with `Upright`, `Italic`, `Bold` and `BoldItalic`?

Comment: @EvanAad XeTeX uses the HarfBuzz and FontConfig libraries.

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR** The font name is *Avenir Book,* *Avenir* is the font family name; *Times New Roman* is both the family and the main font name. Below how to tell them apart and where to find them using Mac FontBook

---

The names you are given in the font book, at least in the portion you shared, are not the real font names, as more the font *family name* or font family description; sometimes they match, but many times they don't. In fact you have many fonts under a single name as you can see from the screenshot.

What you are after are the enhanced bits, which you can see from the **information panel**. This is obtaining by the "i" shaped button on the top left. Sorry for the Italian. What you are after is the *font complete name* or, as an alternate, its *Postscript name*

[image]

[image]

You can see that Avenir is a *family* name which corresponds to no specific font, while *Times New Roman* has a specific font with the same name

Comment: Not really; Avenir Book is the name of a specific font in the Avenir family.

Comment: I've taken away the checkmark gave you because, as @egreg has pointed out, your answer seems to be incorrect in stating that the `Avenir`font family's name is really `Avenir Book`. This point seems to be further demonstrated by @egreg's answer, which shows that XeTeX *is* able to make sense of the font family `Avenir`. Sorry for the flip-flop.

Comment: @EvanAad I never (willingly) claimed that avenir book was *the* font name. It seemed the font you were looking for. If my wording failed me fine. You can trust egreg anyway