# 'font-not-found' error when using either the Courier or the Courier Regular fonts with fontspec + luatex

Tags: errors, luatex, fontspec

The following document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Courier}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

doesn't compile with the LuaLaTeX format (i.e. with the LuaLaTeX "engine"), and results in the following error message:

> ERROR: fontspec error: "font-not-found"
>
> --- TeX said ---
>   !
>   ! The font "Courier" cannot be found.
>   !
>   ! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
>   !
>   ! For immediate help type H .
>   !...............................................
>
> l.3 \setmainfont{Courier}
>
> --- HELP ---
>   From the .log file...
>
> |'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
>   | A font might not be found for many reasons.
>   |  Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.
>   |
>   |  When in doubt, ask someone for help!
>   |...............................................

Here's the `Courier` listing in my Font Book:

[image: Courier font in Font Book]

and here's the corresponding font info page:

[image: Courier font info]

---

This post is closely related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374279/21685), however [@Moriambar's answer to that post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374284/21685) doesn't apply to the present case, and also the error is different (`font-not-found` here vs. `table index is nill` there).

---

**Operating System**: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5
**MacTex distribution**: MacTeX-2017
**LuaTeX**: Version 1.0.4

Comment: this might be related to the fact that this is a `dfont` and not an opentype one

Comment: @Moriambar yes see my answer

Comment: Incidentally, Mac has Courier New as a font that in its bold variant looks quite similar to the standard courier one. That one also works within LuaTex, maybe it is an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dfont format is not supported in recent versions of luatex, see

https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/blob/master/NEWS

> - Remove support for builtin Fontforge libraries (this includes the PFA,
>     PFB, DFONT, and feature file readers).

You may have the Courier also available as truetype or opentype (or if not, I understand that there are font utilities available on the mac to make that conversion, although I do not have a Mac to give details).

Comment: I couldn't have known this. Nice answer ;)